# jQuery Draggable and transparent PNGs - draggable areas being obstructed by transparent backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I have a bunch of images to which I'm applying `jQuery.draggable()`

They are transparent PNGs, and as such have transparent backgrounds. The issue is that their backgrounds are being treated as draggable areas, and as such, if an element is in the background then a foreground element's transparent background blocks the background element from being dragged.

**Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BT2A9/) of the problem**

What's the solution to this? Is there any way for jQuery to automatically ignore transparent areas of an image and only treat visible areas as a draggable handle?

Comment: The issue isn't really something that jQuery (or any other library) can do much about. The rules about how/when events are fired are controlled by the browser.

Comment: Hm, you could play with image maps. In certain situations, it could work.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: I did consider image maps, however I have lots of dynamically changing images and it would be a far more elegant solution if I could somehow "ignore" transparent areas of an image.

Comment: @RobertHawkins Then this does not seem to be one of those certain situations :). Maybe canvas?

Comment: The problem is that a transparency on an image is not a hole, its a transparent layer which you are clicking on. which you have specifically said should be on top (due to the z-index). Its working as intended and there's not a lot you can do about it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and a jQuery plugin was implemented a while ago. Here is a [demo](http://alphadesigns.com.au/pixelselect/test.html) (multi sublayers not enabled, still a bit buggy). The [author's demo site](http://www.cw-internetdienste.de/pixelselection/) has gone down but the code is still available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Bahlor/jQuery-Pixel-Related-Object-Selection). Build off this and implement your dragging.

Comment: Thanks for taking note of my plugin :) The website is back online, had some server issues. Also a much more enhanced version is online since a few weeks.